# Does Window_SUM really sort the data in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Does WINDOW_SUM actually sort the data? what if my table looks like this

userid | price

```
   1 | 5

   2 | 6

   3 | 7

   1 | 10
```

and say I need the output like below (just one column)

total_price_by_user

```
 15

  6

  7
```

clearly I need a sum distinct as a calculated field so I can do the below but I wonder if window_sum actually sorts the data or not and the userid should not be displayed in the output so it should exactly look like above?

WINDOW_SUM(IIF(ATTR([userid])==ZN(LOOKUP(ATTR([userid]), -1)), 0, [price]))

Answer (score 0):

You are working too hard.

Just put make sure Userid is a discrete (blue) dimension and then place it on a shelf, such as the Rows shelf. Then make sure price is a continuous (green) measure and place it on a shelf, such se the Columns shelf. Tableau will aggregate the data and display the sum of all the price values for each user id.

To change a field from dimension to measure, simply drag it to the appropriate section in the data pane on the left (i.e. the pane showing all the field names)

If you want Tableau to sort your users by sum, click the sort button in the toolbar.

Save table calculations like Window_Sum() and lookup() for the occasional special cases that  the simpler approaches don't cover.